# Spring Boot WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter Login Redirect

Tags: redirect, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

I am using the following WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter code in a Spring Boot application:

```
    @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("USER").anyRequest().permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("EADM").anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                    .usernameParameter("personContactEmail").passwordParameter("personRegPwd")
                    .successHandler(secureAuthenticationSuccessHandler) 
            .and()
                .logout()
                    .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                    .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .and()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler());
}
```

When I try to access the /user page without authenticating, the app redirects me to the login page, but when I try to access the /admin page without authenticating, the app takes me to the admin home page?

I have setup a custom AuthenticationSuccessHandler. When I debug and call the /user page, it goes in here, but with /admin it does not even reach this method. I am not sure what I am missing here?

```
  protected String determineTargetUrl(Authentication authentication) {
  boolean isUser = false;
  boolean isAdmin = false;
  Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = authentication.getAuthorities();

  for (GrantedAuthority grantedAuthority : authorities) {
      if (grantedAuthority.getAuthority().equals("ROLE_USER")) {
          isUser = true;
          break;
      } else if (grantedAuthority.getAuthority().equals("ROLE_EADM")) {
          isAdmin = true;
          break;
      }
  }

  if (isUser) 
  {
      return "/user";
  } 
  else if (isAdmin) 
  {
      return "/admin";
  } 
  else 
  {
      throw new IllegalStateException();
  }
}
```

Any Help Please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> .authorizeRequests()
>               .antMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("USER").anyRequest().permitAll()
>               .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("EADM").anyRequest().permitAll()

antMatchers() and anyRequest() both create [RequestMatchers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/util/matcher/RequestMatcher.html) ([AntPathRequestMatcher](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/util/matcher/AntPathRequestMatcher.html) and [AnyRequestMatcher](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/util/matcher/AnyRequestMatcher.html) respectively) and return a RequestMatcherConfigurer. The RequestMatchers in a given [RequestMatcherConfigurer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.RequestMatcherConfigurer.html) are then applied sequentially when a request is processed. The first valid match is used to determine whether or not the user will be able to access the page. For this reason, your matchers should be ordered from most specific to least specific

*.antMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("USER")* is processed first, so /user/** requires ROLE_USER. *.anyRequest().permitAll()* is second, so when a request to /admin/** is processed, this request will match permitAll() and the user will be granted access to the page and  *.antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("EADM")* will never be processed.

This should be resolved by removing the first *.anyRequest().permitAll()*. like this:

```
... 
http
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("USER")
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("EADM")
        .anyRequest().permitAll()
    .and()
...
```